# Emptying and refilling a div with sub-divs

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a main div.
I fill this with lots of sub-divs (each containing a word) (click import text)
I have an "onclick" function for the sub-divs which allows user to select them (they change color), and lots of other snazzy stuff
I then clear the main div (I tried both setting innerHTML to "" or killing the children in a loop)
I then refill the main div with sub divs again (click import text another time)
This time, when I click on the "children", although in debug mode (F12) they appear to get the event and they're background color changes programmatically, it does NOT change visually!!

```
  <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
    <style>
    body {
        font-family: tahoma;
        font-size: 12pt;
    }

    .t {
        width:800px; 
        height:300px; 
        background-color:#FFF;
        border: solid 1px #CCF;
    }

    .m {
        width:800px; 
        height:300px; 
        background-color:#EFF;
        border: solid 1px #CCF;

    }

    .d {
        float: left;    
        border-right: solid 1px #CCF;
        border-bottom: solid 1px #CCF;
        padding-left:2px;
        padding-right: 2px;

    }

    .but {
        width:100px;
    }
    </style>
    <script src="../fdlnew.js"></script>
    <script>

    var ss = null;

    function subImport() {
        ss.importText(document.getElementById("textBox").value);
    }



    function doit() {
        document.getElementById("divStat").style.visibility="hidden";

        divMain = document.getElementById("divMain");
        ss = new subit(divMain);
    }    




    function stat (s) {
            statDiv = document.getElementById("divStat");
            statDiv.innerHTML += s + "<br>";        
            statDiv.scrollTop = statDiv.scrollHeight;
    }



    function subit (divMain) {    

        bigThis = this;
        this.divMain    = divMain;
        // some color constants        

        nbg = "#EFF";
        hbg = "orange";                                                
        sbg = "#AFA";
        cbg = "#AAF";

        // the main word object array
        this.warr = [];


        this.importText = function(txt) {
            while ( this.divMain.firstChild ) 
                this.divMain.removeChild( this.divMain.firstChild );

            var parts = txt.split(" ");

            for (i=0; i<parts.length; i++) {
                this.warr[this.warr.length] = new word(i, parts[i], this.divMain);
            }
        }


        function word(id, txt, container) {
            this.txt = txt;
            this.id = id;
            this.div = document.createElement('div');
            this.div.innerHTML = this.txt; //  + "&nbsp;" 
            this.div.className = "d";
            this.div.setAttribute("id", "d" + this.id);
            divMain.appendChild(this.div);
            this.timestamp = 0;

            this.isLastSelected = false;
            this.isSelected = false;
            this.steppedOn = false;

            this.div.onclick = function ()  {
                thisId = parseInt(this.id.substr(1));
                bigThis.warr[thisId].gotClicked();
            }

        }

        word.prototype.gotClicked = function () {

            gLastSel = -1;

            // FIRST, fix ME!!
            if (!this.isSelected) {
                this.isSelected = true;
                this.isLastSelected = true;
                gLastSel = this.id;
            } else {
                this.isSelected = false;
                this.isLastSelected = false;
                gLastSel = -1;
            }
            this.setBG();

            // now we check the others ...
            var nowLastSel = -1;
            for (i=0; i<bigThis.warr.length; i++) {
                if (bigThis.warr[i].id != this.id && bigThis.warr[i].isSelected ) {
                    if (!event.ctrlKey && this.isSelected) {
                        bigThis.warr[i].isSelected = false;
                        bigThis.warr[i].isLastSelected = false;
                    } else {
                        if (bigThis.warr[i].isLastSelected) {
                            if (gLastSel == -1)  gLastSel = i;
                            else                bigThis.warr[i].isLastSelected = false;
                        }


                        nowLastSel = i;
                    }
                }
                bigThis.warr[i].setBG();
            }
            if (gLastSel==-1)   gLastSel = nowLastSel;
            if (gLastSel!=-1) {
                bigThis.warr[gLastSel].isLastSelected = true;
                bigThis.warr[gLastSel].setBG();
            }
        }

        word.prototype.stepOn = function (ts) {
            if (wordCurStep!=-1) 
                bigThis.warr[wordCurStep].stepOff();

            this.timestamp = ts;
            this.steppedOn = true;
            wordCurStep = this.id;
            this.setBG();
        }

        word.prototype.stepOff = function () {
            this.steppedOn = false;
            this.setBG();
            wordCurStep = -1;
        }

        word.prototype.setBG = function () {
            var bgcol = nbg;
            if (this.steppedOn) {
                bgcol  = hbg;
            } else {
                if (this.isSelected) 
                    bgcol = this.isLastSelected ? cbg : sbg;
            }
            this.div.style.backgroundColor = bgcol;
        }

        word.prototype.getText = function() {   return(this.txt);                       }
        word.prototype.setStamp = function(stamp) { this.stamp = stamp;                 }    
        word.prototype.getStamp = function() {  return(this.stamp);                     }

    }



    </script>
    </head>

    <body  onload = "doit();">

    1. Paste Text Here: <br>
    <textarea  id="textBox" class="t" rows="10" >
    Marconi was born in Bologna in 1874. From 1890 to 1893, he studied physics at the technical school in Livorno. 
    In 1894 he started experimenting with radio waves and discovered how to transmit them over short distances. 
    Unfortunately he did not receive much encouragement in Italy and his English relatives advised him to go to Britain. 
    In February 1896 he arrived in London where the British Post Office provided him with facilities to continue his research.
    </textarea><br>
    <input type="button" value="Import Text"   class="but"     onclick="subImport();">



        <div id="divMain" class="m"></div>

    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: I'm a bit confused about your code. You use `document.getElementById("divStat")`, but there is no element with id `divStat`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is the `warr` array. When the button "Import text" is clicked, the words from the text are pushed into `warr`, but if there are already words in `warr`, they aren't removed. You have to reset `warr` whenever `subit.importText` is called:

```
this.importText = function(txt) {
    this.warr = [];

    // ...
}
```

[See jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/7pmwzqfr/1/)

```js
var ss = null;

function subImport() {
    ss.importText(document.getElementById("textBox").value);
}


function doit() {
    document.getElementById("divStat").style.visibility = "hidden";

    divMain = document.getElementById("divMain");
    ss = new subit(divMain);
}
doit(); // instead of <body onload="doit();">


function stat(s) {
    statDiv = document.getElementById("divStat");
    statDiv.innerHTML += s + "<br>";
    statDiv.scrollTop = statDiv.scrollHeight;
}



function subit(divMain) {

    bigThis = this;
    this.divMain = divMain;
    
    // some color constants
    nbg = "#EFF";
    hbg = "orange";
    sbg = "#AFA";
    cbg = "#AAF";

    // the main word object array
    this.warr = [];


    this.importText = function(txt) {
     this.warr = []; // Was missing!
    
        while (this.divMain.firstChild)
            // using innerHTML would be fine too!
            this.divMain.removeChild(this.divMain.firstChild);

        var parts = txt.split(" ");

        for (i = 0; i < parts.length; i++) {
            // why not use this.warr.push() ?
            this.warr[this.warr.length] = new word(i, parts[i], this.divMain);
        }
    }


    function word(id, txt, container) {
        this.txt = txt;
        this.id = id;
        this.div = document.createElement('div');
        this.div.innerHTML = this.txt; //  + "&nbsp;" 
        this.div.className = "d";
        this.div.setAttribute("id", "d" + this.id);
        divMain.appendChild(this.div);
        this.timestamp = 0;

        this.isLastSelected = false;
        this.isSelected = false;
        this.steppedOn = false;

        this.div.onclick = function() {
            thisId = parseInt(this.id.substr(1));
            bigThis.warr[thisId].gotClicked();
        }

    }

    word.prototype.gotClicked = function() {

        gLastSel = -1;

        // Here is no problem!
        if (!this.isSelected) {
            this.isSelected = true;
            this.isLastSelected = true;
            gLastSel = this.id;
        } else {
            this.isSelected = false;
            this.isLastSelected = false;
            gLastSel = -1;
        }
        this.setBG();

        // now we check the others ...
        var nowLastSel = -1;
        for (i = 0; i < bigThis.warr.length; i++) {
            if (bigThis.warr[i].id != this.id && bigThis.warr[i].isSelected) {
                if (!event.ctrlKey && this.isSelected) {
                    bigThis.warr[i].isSelected = false;
                    bigThis.warr[i].isLastSelected = false;
                } else {
                    if (bigThis.warr[i].isLastSelected) {
                        if (gLastSel == -1) gLastSel = i;
                        else bigThis.warr[i].isLastSelected = false;
                    }


                    nowLastSel = i;
                }
            }
            bigThis.warr[i].setBG();
        }
        if (gLastSel == -1) gLastSel = nowLastSel;
        if (gLastSel != -1) {
            bigThis.warr[gLastSel].isLastSelected = true;
            bigThis.warr[gLastSel].setBG();
        }
    }

    word.prototype.stepOn = function(ts) {
        if (wordCurStep != -1)
            bigThis.warr[wordCurStep].stepOff();

        this.timestamp = ts;
        this.steppedOn = true;
        wordCurStep = this.id;
        this.setBG();
    }

    word.prototype.stepOff = function() {
        this.steppedOn = false;
        this.setBG();
        wordCurStep = -1;
    }

    word.prototype.setBG = function() {
        var bgcol = nbg;
        if (this.steppedOn) {
            bgcol = hbg;
        } else {
            if (this.isSelected)
                bgcol = this.isLastSelected ? cbg : sbg;
        }
        this.div.style.backgroundColor = bgcol;
    }

    word.prototype.getText = function() {
        return (this.txt);
    }
    word.prototype.setStamp = function(stamp) {
        this.stamp = stamp;
    }
    word.prototype.getStamp = function() {
        return (this.stamp);
    }

}
```

```css
body {
    font-family: tahoma;
    font-size: 12pt;
}

.t {
    width: 800px;
    height: 300px;
    background-color: #FFF;
    border: solid 1px #CCF;
}

.m {
    width: 800px;
    height: 300px;
    background-color: #EFF;
    border: solid 1px #CCF;
}

.d {
    float: left;
    border-right: solid 1px #CCF;
    border-bottom: solid 1px #CCF;
    padding-left: 2px;
    padding-right: 2px;
}

.but {
    width: 100px;
}
```

```html
1. Paste Text Here:
<br>
<textarea id="textBox" class="t" rows="10">
    Marconi was born in Bologna in 1874. From 1890 to 1893, he studied physics at the technical school in Livorno. In 1894 he started experimenting with radio waves and discovered how to transmit them over short distances. Unfortunately he did not receive
    much encouragement in Italy and his English relatives advised him to go to Britain. In February 1896 he arrived in London where the British Post Office provided him with facilities to continue his research.
</textarea>
<br>
<input type="button" value="Import Text" class="but" onclick="subImport();">



<div id="divMain" class="m"></div>

<!-- id=divStat needed so no error is encountered -->
<div id="divStat">Hidden!</div>
```

Comment: OMG, what an idiot!!! All I had to do was: warr.length = 0; !!!! THANKS a bunch.. I've been stuck for a whole day.

Comment: `warr.length = 0` does not change the content of the array. In this case it might work, but I wouldn't recommend it. Just overwrite the array with a new, empty array.

Comment: Thanks! I always thought that arr.length=0 and arr= [] were equivalent for emptying an existing array!

Comment: Sorry, I just realized that you were right. Setting the length also affects the actual size of the array. My bad!